# Oracle - drop errored view

Tags: oracle

I have a Oracle view where when trying to view, replace, or even drop the view it shows below error:

```
DROP X.z force
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06553: PLS-707: unsupported construct or internal error [2604], [403]
ORA-06553: PLS-103: Encountered the symbol "Vendor " when expecting one of
the following:
<an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
ORA-06553: PLS-112: end-of-line in quoted identifier
```

The column mentioned mistakenly have a break line 
(it is: "Vendor
Name"). The problem that I cannot replace, rename or even drop to fix the issue.
Is there any way I can forcedly drop it or recreate ?!

Comment: Have a look at [MoS Doc ID 2254717.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2254717.1).

Comment: I just created a view with a column with a newline in it, selected from it (worked OK), and then dropped it. It worked perfectly. I am not able to reproduce the scenario you are reporting. Is that `DROP` statement stand-alone, run by itself from SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer or such? Or is it, explicitly or implicitly, wrapped in some PL/SQL code? **That** may cause the issue (this is, clearly, a PL/SQL error). If so, then drop the view simply from SQL\*Plus.

Comment: @mathguy we'll it seems it is not the break line itself, somehow the view query got corrupted. tried all tools same error. The document mentioned is the exact issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what is described in [My Oracle Support Doc ID 2254717.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2254717.1), which seems to be about exactly this problem, you should be able to do something like:

```
column object_id new_value bad_object_id;

select object_name, object_type, owner, status, object_id
from all_objects
where object_type='VIEW' and owner='X' and object_name = 'Z';

OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE         OWNER                          STATUS   OBJECT_ID
------------------------------ ------------------- ------------------------------ ------- ----------
Z                              VIEW                X                              VALID       445264

exec dbms_utility.invalidate(&bad_object_id);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

select object_name, object_type, owner, status, object_id
from all_objects
where object_type='VIEW' and owner='X' and object_name = 'Z';

OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE         OWNER                          STATUS   OBJECT_ID
------------------------------ ------------------- ------------------------------ ------- ----------
Z                              VIEW                X                              INVALID     445264

drop view X.z;

View X.Z dropped.
```

I've used substitution variables but you can just manually enter the object ID of course.

I haven't been able to figure out how to recreate the issue - the MoS doc seems to also not know how it happened, though in that case was from an 11g to 12c upgrade, and can only speculate vaguely about corruption. I tried exporting and importing a view using the same versions but it still didn't complain. So I haven't been able to verify this will actually work as advertised, but it looks like it should...